# Ubuntu 14.04 Black Screen after login - Tried Everything

Tags: 14.04, server, login, restart

I restarted my Ubuntu 14.04, and it brought up the login screen so I logged in and there was nothing but a black screen. I searched the web and tried about 15 fixes, but nothing worked.

Something similar to this happened before: I was stuck in a login loop (I would login, the screen would flash, and the login screen would come up again). The only solution I found for that was a re-install of the OS, which I really can't afford to do again (I have a site that runs off this computer and I need to have it up again).

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Most probably graphics card driver issue. please specify what graphics card you have?

Comment: I have an Nvidia GT 610. I've done apt-get purge nvidia*, but that hasn't seemed to help.... Also, if I do sudo start from tty, I get the desktop, but without the menu bars and stuff, just the background and the files on my desktop... @Ashu

Comment: Can anyone help?? I need my server back up ASAP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: It's not because I'm not booting to  black screen and none of the issues/fixes in that thread apply to me/fix my problem @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : Remove all NVIDIA software you have installed.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install NVIDIA drivers 352 from the repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Note: just doing the driver thing as you suggested didn't work by itself. It seems that I had also lost ownership of my Xauthority file. It worked by using sudo rm ~/.Xauthority after reinstalling the drivers.